# ERROR: 22001: value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

there! I am using PostgreSQL + NHibernate. I have 4 fields in mapping file:

```
<property name="Name" not-null="false" type="String"/>
<property name="Include" not-null="false" type="String"/>
<property name="Exclude" not-null="false" type="String"/>
```

When I compile the code there are many insertions queries into the DB. PostgreSQL gives me this error

> "ERROR: 22001: value too long for type character varying(255)"

I know there is "text" type in the PostgreSQL capabilities of storing data. How could I make NHibernate provide my fields with "text"-type?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! I should define mapped fields as:

```
<property name="Name" not-null="false" type="StringClob"/>
<property name="Include" not-null="false" type="StringClob"/>
<property name="Exclude" not-null="false" type="StringClob"/>
```